# Meaning of "To be the last person to do something" in a group of people

Tags: meaning, expressions

Me and two of my friends share a pie. They ask me: "Do you want to be the last person to take a piece from this pie?" I answer: "Yes".

Do I now get to eat only the last piece or the third piece which might not be the last one?

Comment: Your question specifies 'taking', not 'eating'. Strictly speaking, you could all take a piece, but none of you eat it. It also depends on how many pieces the pie is cut into - assuming 'share' implies division into equal pieces, then the number of pieces will always be divisible by three. If divided into 9, and the question is asked before anyone takes a piece, your friends could each take 4 pieces, leaving you the last, or they could take 2 each, leaving you 5. Either way, you would have the last piece. Whether you get to eat it depends on how hungry you are ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic, not English.

Answer (score 1):

Are you all only allowed to have a single piece?

If **Yes**, then you get to eat only the last piece.
If **No**, you ARE allowed to have more, you may have more pieces before having the last one too.